# Pop() not return any value when inside a function?

Tags: python, list

I'm currently learning about the `pop()` function in Python and have a question.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.pop(3) #or a.pop()
4
>>> print(a)
[1,2,3]
```

I get that the `pop()` function removes and returns the value of the element corresponding to the index. However, the following example is the reason why I'm confused:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> def solution(array):
        array.pop()
        return array
>>> solution(a)
[1,2,3]
```

First, I get that the function that I've described returns [1,2,3]. However, why does it not return the `pop()` value? Shouldn't it return `4` since the `pop()` function inside the `solution()` has a `pop()` function which, in definition, returns the value of the popped element?? I thought this `pop()` function kind of acts like `del` and `print` function simultaneously.

Comment: `return` and `print` are completely different things. It's easy to mix them up in interactive mode because interactive mode auto-prints a lot of values, but returning a thing does not mean printing it.

Comment: I think you're confusing how the REPL operates vs how values get returned. `pop()` doesn't print anything. That is the REPL showing the last expression evaulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `return` array after `array.pop()` it will return the rest of the element expcept the `pop`. Because you are returning array not all the specific pop opereation. Return `array.pop()` instead of `array`

```
def solution(array):
    return array.pop()
```

Or another way you can store the pop element and then you can return the pop variable.

```
def solution(array):
    pop_op=array.pop()
    return pop_op
```

Comment: I get that the function you've described returns the popped element, but what I want to know is the reason why mine doesn't return the popped element

Comment: @SihwanLee the function returns what the `return` statement tells it to.  If you tell it to return `array`, that's what it will return.

Answer (score 2):

cause you are not catching what `pop()` returns, the element is never printed, just in the python shell, you are returning the array modified, not the value returned by `pop()`.

Edit:
Btw , you don't need to return the array, the original array is already modified.